# Почему не работает код? Как исправить?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

код не может увидеть context и user, что делать?
main.dart

```
import 'dart:js';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:project_c/pages/Home.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: new MyHomePage(),

    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}




class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String _email, _password;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 110.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                          child: Text(
                              'Hello',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 80.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 175.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                          child: Text(
                              'Gamer',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 80.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(250.0, 175.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                          child: Text(
                              '.',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 80.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  color: Colors.green)
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 330.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),

                            child: Form(
                              key: _formKey,
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  TextFormField(
                                    validator: (input) {
                                      if (input.isEmpty) {
                                        return 'Provide an email';
                                      }
                                    },
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        labelText: 'EMAIL',


                                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: Colors.grey
                                        ),
                                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                color: Colors.green)
                                        )

                                    ),
                                    onSaved: (input) => _email = input,

                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                                  TextFormField(
                                    validator: (input) {
                                      if (input.length < 6) {
                                        return 'Longer password please';
                                      }
                                    },
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        labelText: 'PASSWORD',
                                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: Colors.grey
                                        ),
                                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                                color: Colors.green)
                                        )

                                    ),
                                    onSaved: (input) => _password = input,
                                    obscureText: true,

                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 5.0,),
                                  Container(
                                    alignment: Alignment(1.0, 0.0),
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        top: 15.0, left: 20.0),
                                    child: InkWell(
                                      child: Text('Forgot password',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.green,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                              decoration: TextDecoration
                                                  .underline)
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(height: 40.0),
                                  Container(
                                    height: 40.0,
                                    child: Material(

                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                      shadowColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                                      color: Colors.green,
                                      elevation: 7.0,
                                      child: RaisedButton(

                                        onPressed: signIn,
                                        child: Center(
                                          child: Text(

                                            'LOGIN',
                                            style: TextStyle(

                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat'

                                            ),

                                          ),
                                        ),


                                      ),


                                    ),
                                  ),

                                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                                  Container(
                                    height: 40.0,


                                    child: Material(

                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                      shadowColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      elevation: 7.0,
                                      child: GestureDetector(

                                        onTap: () {},
                                        child: Center(
                                          child: Text(

                                            'REGISTER',
                                            style: TextStyle(

                                                color: Colors.black,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat'

                                            ),

                                          ),
                                        ),


                                      ),


                                    ),


                                  )


                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                        )

                      ]
                  )
              )


            ]

        )



    );


  }

  Future<void> signIn() async{
    final formState = _formKey.currentState;
    if(formState.validate()){
      formState.save();
      try{
        UserCredential user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _password);
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home(user: user)));
      }catch(e){
        print(e.message);
      }

    }

  }



  }
```

dart аналитика
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из-за того, что под капотом `import 'dart:js'` есть упоминания про свой `context` он перетягивает `JsObject`, а не  `BuildContext`, просто удали этот импорт(`import 'dart:js';`) или пометь его
`import 'dart:js' as js;`